# Decrease the length of a list while iterating over its items

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, list, counter

**Problem:**
There are 2 lists, one is considered the parent, and the other is the child. What I want to do is to construct a 3rd list based on a condition.

**Current Solution:**

```
from netaddr import *

l1 = ['10.0.0.0/8', '172.16.0.0/16']
l2 =['10.10.10.10','172.16.15.0/24','10.20.10.0/24','13.1.1.0/24','15.10.10.0/24','172.16.16.0/25','10.10.11.11']

[ip1 for ip1 in l1 for ip2 in l2 if IPNetwork(ip2) in IPNetwork(ip1)]
```

**Output:**

```
['10.0.0.0/8', '10.0.0.0/8', '10.0.0.0/8', '172.16.0.0/16', '172.16.0.0/16']
```

The above comprehension, in my opinion, isn't an optimal solution

I am looking to **find a way by which I could re-implement the above solution** with the added advantage of removing the elements (refer ip2) that are matched from l2 in every iteration, thus avoid rechecking those elements again in the next iteration

Comment: Tip for the future: don't use the 'quote' markup to highlgiht text. Don't use capitals and refrain from using too many stylistic changes if the mere reason is to draw attention.

Comment: Judging by your question and the auxiliary information, you might be trying to solve the wrong problem. Can you explain how supernet, networks and addresses translate to the two lists? Also, do you know how a ``set`` and  ``item in container`` checks work?

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I'm not sure what you mean by "translate to the two lists" but I have a clear problem; a list which has a CIRD/Supernet which is considered like a top of the tree.

On the other side, I have another list with more-specific networks and addresses, and I want to categorize these addresses based upon the supernet

Comment: Does the number and order of matches matter?

Answer (score 0):

Here a solution with counter and set.

Furthermore, it defines the IPNetwork objects only one time, which is the slowest operation (it costs 50µs when `n2 in n1` costs only 5µs).

```
from collections import Counter
cnt=Counter()
S2=set(IPNetwork(ad2) for ad2 in l2)
for ad1 in l1:
    n1=IPNetwork(ad1)
    found=set()
    for n2 in S2: 
        if n2 in n1:
            cnt[ad1]+=1
            found.add(n2)
    S2 -= found
```

Finally `cnt` is  `Counter({'10.0.0.0/8': 3, '172.16.0.0/16': 2})` and `S2` is `{IPNetwork('13.1.1.0/24'), IPNetwork('15.10.10.0/24')}`.